# Индекс Radiobutton.Tag вышел за границы массива C# Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radiobutton

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Решил в программе сохранять позиции Radiobutton'ов через теги и параметры, которые записываю в свойствах проекта. Сделал с одним набором Radiobutton'ов - получилось, решил сделать второй, но тут уже начались проблемы, так как программа начала выдавать исключение о выходе за границы массива.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.checkedRB = checkedRB;
    Properties.Settings.Default.checkedRB1 = checkedRB1;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    Parent.Show();
    Close();
}
void rb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //обработчик CheckedChanged для каждого radiobutton
{
    if ((sender as RadioButton).Checked)
    {
        checkedRB = int.Parse((sender as RadioButton).Tag.ToString());

    }
}
void rb1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //обработчик CheckedChanged для каждого radiobutton
{
    if ((sender as RadioButton).Checked)
    {
        checkedRB1 = int.Parse((sender as RadioButton).Tag.ToString());
    }
}
private void Form2_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormClosing += Form2_FormClosing;
    checkedRB1 = Properties.Settings.Default.checkedRB1;
    (new RadioButton[] { radioButton1, radioButton2 })[checkedRB1].Checked = true;
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        infoLabel.Text = "Текущие дата и время:";
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Items.Add(infoLabel);
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Items.Add(dateLabel);
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Items.Add(timeLabel);
        timer = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 };
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }
    else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        infoLabel.Text = "Текущие дата и время:";
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Items.Add(infoLabel);
        dateLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Items.Add(dateLabel);
        DayLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Items.Add(DayLabel);
    }
    checkedRB = Properties.Settings.Default.checkedRB;
    (new RadioButton[] { radioButton3, radioButton4, radioButton5, radioButton6 })[checkedRB].Checked = true;
}
```

Жалуется вот на эту строку:

```
(new RadioButton[] { radioButton1, radioButton2 })[checkedRB1].Checked = true;
```

Код вызова второй формы:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    //2.TopLevel = false;
    Hide();
    f2.ShowDialog(this);
    //f2.StartPosition = StartPosition;
}
```

Comment: Допустимые значения для `checkedRB1` 0 и 1, а у вас там что? Что делает `button3_Click` или что оно должно делать?

Comment: @aepot В checkedRB1 0 и 1, button3_Click присваивает значения переменных checkedRB и checkedRB1 параметрам в свойствах и сохраняет данные настройки

Comment: А зачем оно создает ещё одно окно? Какую проблему вы решаете пересозданием окна? Если убрать последние 3 строчки из этого метода, что получится?

Comment: Давайте начнем с отладки. Что будет если перед проблемной строкой вставить `MessageBox.Show("checkredRB: "+ checkedRB);`? Не лучший способ отладки, зато всем понятен :)

Comment: @aeropot Окно, в котором я делаю это, называется настройками, и в нем помимо radiobutton'ов есть другие кнопки, которые настраивают цвет форм, шрифт и прочее. Данная кнопка является кнопкой применения изменений и возврата на главную форму, на которой мы можем перейти к остальным формам.

Comment: Вы не возвращаетесь в главную форму, вы создаете дочернюю модальную форму, а текущую скрываете, но не закрываете. С большой вероятностью, когда вы закроете приложение, оно останется висеть в памяти вечно.

Comment: @default locale checkedRB = 0, checkedRB1 = 4. Проблемная строка как раз выводит исключение о выходе за границы массива и показывает, чему равно checkedRB1 на данном этапе

Comment: Ну вот, 4, а должно быть 0 или 1

Comment: @Defined123 Теперь осталось понять почему `checkedRB1 = 4`, ведь должно быть не больше 3. Отследите все места где оно изменяется.

Comment: @aepot Да, согласен, но проблема в данный момент не в этом, поскольку checkedRB1 = 4, и я не понимаю, откуда взялось это число, учитывая то, что начальное значение checkedRB1 в свойствах проекта я указываю 0, а значения Tag радиобаттонам присваиваю 0 и 1 соответственно.

Comment: Когда вы открываете окно настроек, вы скрываете главную форму, верно? Поробуйте убрать `Hide()` и вы увидите, что окошки у вас начнут плодиться как грибы после дождя при открытии и закрытии формы настроек. Это ошибка, отсюда много проблем.

Comment: Покажите метод, где вы создаете `Form2`. Покажите все места в коде, где вы изменяете `Properties.Settings.Default.checkedRB1`.

Comment: Есть ли у вас `RadioButton` с тегом 4? К какому обработчику событий она привязана, что делает этот обработчик?

Comment: @aepot Я решил передать значения Radiobutton'ов в другие формы, чтобы при выборе определенного Radiobutton'а у меня дата выводилась либо в одном виде, либо в другом. Заметил, что приходится создавать несколько раз дочерние модальные формы как при загрузке главной формы, так и при переходе к другим формам через кнопку. Видимо, в этом действительно что-то есть.

Comment: @aepot Radiobutton с тегом 4 у меня нет, есть только еще один массив Radiobutton, состоящий из 4-ех других Radiobutton, которые имеют теги от 0 до 3. Это все отражено в коде сверху. Других мест в коде, которые обращаются к Properties.Settings.Default.checkedRB1, у меня нет.

Comment: `Form2 f2 = new Form2(); Hide(); f2.ShowDialog();` Так ведь форму настроек вызываете? Попробуйте так `Form2 f2 = new Form2(); f2.Parent = this; Hide(); f2.ShowDialog();` а в форме настроек поменяйте `Form1 f1 = new Form1(); Hide(); f1.ShowDialog();` на `Parent.Show(); Close();` Как разберетесь с этим, обновите код в вопросе. И кто его знает, может оно и заработает.

Comment: @aepot Выдает исключение "Элемент верхнего уровня нельзя добавлять к элементу управления.". Попробовал ввести f2.TopLevel = false, но в таком случае форма попросту не открывается.

Comment: Покажите код создания `Form2` и обновленный метод закрытия формы настроек. Вслепую сложно что-либо понять. Вероятно, вы что-то перепутали.

Comment: @aepot Можно как-нибудь скинуть Вам проект? Просто боюсь, что все мои действия займут много времени

Comment: @aepot Обновил код в обсуждении

Comment: прошу прощения, тогда `f2.Parent = this;` надо убрать, вместо этого сделать вот так `f2.ShowDialog(this);` Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217716/set-the-parent-of-a-form) много вариантов как установить родителя у дочерней формы, чтобы через него обращаться к родительской.

Comment: @aepot Это сработало, форма по факту открывается, но при проверке CheckedRB1 все равно получается 4 и выскакивает исключение, значит, надо копать глубже. Как вы думаете, методы rb1_CheckedChanged и rb_CheckedChanged могут как-то не так работать в данном случае?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108075/discussion-between-defined123-and-aepot).

Comment: @aepot Здравствуйте! Не отвлекаю?

Comment: @Defined123 StackOverflow - это не чат и не форум. Если у вас есть вопрос - используйте кнопку "Задать вопрос".